# Question regarding pattern recognition in a table

Tags: soft-question, pattern-recognition

Knowing this is a seemingly weird question, I do believe I should provide some additional context . One of our university professor's has a terribly peculiar habit . Namely, each year, the students who take his course have to sit through two written papers and are supposed to present a practical project to the professor . For the last 6 years or so, enough data was gathered by the students to arrive at the conclusion that the grades for the two written papers are assigned completely regardless of what the students wrote in them .

The conclusion is based on the following recurring facts :

---

- The professor never shows the papers, never provides any explanation concerning the grades .
- Students who weren't present at the test were graded, others who did perfectly got impossibly low grades and others who did poorly got grades close to the maximum.
- Three students which took the course two years ago managed to write a C program that would generate a number pattern almost identical with the paper grades in that year  (they won't share it for their safety) .
- The paper grades are only disclosed to us after we present a project that's evaluated by the professor in front of us.

---

For the most part of the day and the night before, I've been trying to crack the pattern but I got mostly nothing except that the grades in the papers are usually within a $5$ point gap compared to the grade in the project.

[image]

For privacy issues, the name of the students have been cropped out . First two columns make for the two written papers in chronological order, the third is the grade assigned for the project and the fourth is obviously the total .

Can anyone discern any mathematical pattern ?